# two ListView not working on NavigationDrawer

Tags: java, android, listview, navigation-drawer

I have two `ListView` in my `NavigationDrawer`, both of them is displayed on my `NavigationDrawer`, but I face a problem, when user want to click an item from one `ListView`, it does't work, this is how I call `setOnItemClickListener` from my `ListView`:

```
  list_terbaru=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_terbaru);
    list_terkirim=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_terkirim);
    list_terbaru.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
    list_terkirim.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

 private class SlideMenuClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,  View v, int position, long arg3) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.list_terbaru:
        id=((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.nomor_registrasi)).getText().toString();
        a=id;
         ModelHelper.onModel(me);
         getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,new PemegangPolis()).commit();
         selectItem(position);
        break;
        case R.id.list_terkirim:
id=((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.no_polis)).getText().toString();
        a="";
        ModelHelper.onModel(me);
             getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,new PemegangPolis()).commit();
         selectItembaru(position);

    }
} 
}

 private void selectItem(int position) {
     ModelHelper.onModel(me);
     ModelHelper.onRetrieve(helper,id,me,position,model,SelectPemegang,SelectTertanggung,SelectUA,SelectDi,SelectDA,SelectDP);
     getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,new PemegangPolis()).commit();
//      helper.close();selectItem
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(SlidingMenu);
 } 
 private void selectItembaru(int position) {
     ModelHelper.onModel(me);
     ModelHelper.onRetrieve(helper,id,me,position,model2,SelectPemegang,SelectTertanggung,SelectUA,SelectDi,SelectDA,SelectDP);
     getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,new PemegangPolis()).commit();
//      helper.close();selectItem
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(SlidingMenu);
 }
```

so my question, is it possible to call 'onItemClick' with `switch (v.getId())`? and if it is possible, can anyone help me to show where is fault? and how I can solve my problem? thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R.id.list_terbaru` and `R.id.list_terkirim` are the ids of the `ListView`s. However `v` is not the `ListView`, but the `View` of the item. Switch on the id of the `AdapterView` (which is one of your `ListView`s in this case) instead:

```
switch (arg0.getId()) {
```

If there is no other error in the code (could not find one), this should solve the problem.

But have you considered creating different listeners for the lists? That way you wouldn't have to switch at all.

Comment: using this code `switch (arg0.getId())`, thank you for your help :)